# Enum on array with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to the documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators):

> Strings have enum, match, maxlength and minlength validators.

*(the link does point to an invalid zone of the doc).*

Is there a way to declare enum on array with mongoose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean an array of enums, that would be:

```
const testSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    enums: [{type: String, enum: ['Coffee', 'Tea']}]
});
```

Comment: Thank you +1! (and sorry about being a bit too vague) Will accept in 3 minutes (I have to wait because SO)